# How can I make this request eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to perform a collective filtering similarity algorithm in an small database with 6k items and 30k users. This is for a research project at my university; I am not a computer scientist; rather a power user. The data was already designated with specific keys so; to save computer time I created the associations with the existing keys.

In my algorithm this snippet takes the longest to execute:

```
def aveRankings(item,user = nil)
  #period
  begdate = '2013-08-10 00:00:00 -0400' #Time.parse('2013-08-10')
  enddate = '2014-08-10 00:00:00 -0400' #Time.parse('2014-08-10')
  if user.nil? then
    return item.rankings.where(created_at: (begdate..enddate) ).average(:value).to_f
  else
    return user.items.where(created_at: (begdate..enddate), ikey: item.ikey).average(:value).to_f
  end
end
```

I read online about n+1 and how it betrays performance. I tried calling .include(:rankings) to eager load the rankings but the code does not behaves as expected.

This is the association with the items:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.

has_many :useritems, foreign_key: "ukey", primary_key: "ukey"
has_many :items, through: :useritems

.
.
end
```

[Similarity algorithm](http://pastebin.com/h5JKZSh0)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I should have included this

```
commonUsers.each do |commonuser|
  a = aveRankings(item,commonuser)
  b = aveRankings(candidateitem,commonuser)
  if a != 0.0 and b != 0.0 then #mysql ave function returns this for 0 rankings
     arra << a - aveRankings(item)
     arrb << b - aveRankings(candidateitem)
  end
end
```

Comment: `I tried calling .include(:rankings) to eager load the rankings but the code does not behaves as expected.` Can you elaborate? Btw, it is `includes(:rankings)`, i.e. plural.

Comment: Yes, so for each candidate_item I try to obtain the average rankings given by each candidate_item_user. Then this average is paired with the average rankings if the item.users. The pairs are processed with the similarity algorithm to calculate how similar the candidate item is the item. The performance goes with each call of the aveRankings function due to the fact that the program must perform a query. I would like to preload rankings that belong to both the user and the item. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is how you avoid at least 3/4 requests:

```
aa = aveRankings(item)
bb = aveRankings(candidateitem)
a = nil 

commonUsers.each do |commonuser|
  a = a || aveRankings(item,commonuser)
  b = aveRankings(candidateitem,commonuser)
  if a != 0.0 and b != 0.0 then #mysql ave function returns this for 0 rankings
    arra << a - aa
    arrb << b - bb
  end
end
```